# Cannot publish custom action with app access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

I feel like I am banging my head against the wall here. I have created some custom objects and one custom action. To submit, I must successfully submit the action.

I use the following code from the "Get Code" button on the OpenGraph page in the developer site.

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_ACCESSS_TOKEN' \
     -F 'content=http://samples.ogp.me/417795554977717' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/myapp:myaction'
```

I get the following response

```
{"error":
  {
    "message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":15
   }
 }
```

Well, I like to think I'm a smart guy. I figure out how to generate my app access token from [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/) and try again.

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_APP_ACCESSS_TOKEN' \
     -F 'content=http://samples.ogp.me/417795554977717' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/myapp:myaction'
```

And then I get this response.

```
{"error":
  {
    "message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":102
   }
 }
```

So I'm clearly in a never ending loop. I've banged my head against this, every which way.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course as soon as I submit, I find the answer by changing various settings.

Rather than delete, I will answer for any who Google this later in life (unless they finally fix it).

Under your App settings, the Advanced tab has a setting called "App Type". If this is set to Native/Desktop, you will not be able to post an action.

However, Facebook's own example code from the "Get Code" button still doesn't work - which is alarming.